# Want to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows XP on an pld PC

Tags: partitioning

MS Windows XP Professsional SP2
Intel Pentium 4 CPU 2.66GHz, 991MB RAM, VIA/S3G UniChrome IGP
My PC is fairly old, about 5 yrs to be exact. Want to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows XP. Please give me the detailed procedure to install it. I am a novice at it so no jargon please. Ok. Thnx. :)

Comment: Do you want to install Ubuntu 13.04 or 14.04?

Comment: On this old machine i would prefer Xubuntu 14.04, take look at this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar

Answer (score 2):

To start you'll have to create 2 partitions. You can do this by using [PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com/). PartedMagic can be installed on a pen drive using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). A partition is a part of your hard drive you designate as separate from the other part. Keep in mind that you should have at least 5 gb of space to run linux but about 40+ gp is recommended if you're going to use it extensively.

After this you can install xp onto one of the partitions like you normally would.

The next step is to install linux onto the other partition (in your case Ubuntu 13.04, which I should mention has expired his support date so you'll receive NO updates.I recommend you to choose 14.04 lts. That version will receive updates for the next 5 years) using recommended settings. Linux will install a grub. The grub will let you choose what operating system you want to boot.

If it doesn't show your xp OS you'll have to run a [boot repair cd](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/). This can also be installed onto a pendrive using unetbootin.

Reboot your computer and it should automatically boot into linux. if you want to change this default behavior you can run a [Grub Customize](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) to set xp as the default OS.

If any part was unclear you can comment on this post